# XSLT - Match and replace every XML attribute value with specific attribute value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I wanted to replace wildcards in a control XML-file from a third-party software.

Unfortunately these wildcards also used as attribute values in this XML-file.

I will give you an example:

```
<control>
  <some-tag id="$wildcard1$" version="3.14">
    <another-tag id="second_level">stackoverflow rocks!</another-tag>
  </some-tag>
  <some-tag id="foo" version="$wildcard2$"/>
  <some-tag id="bar" version="145.31.1"/>
</control>
```

I tried to write a generic transformation with parameters to replace the wildcards in the attribute values.

My biggest problem was, that i don't know the attribute name. So i need to match every attribute in the XML file. That is easy **but how i match every attribute with a specific value (e.g. $wildcard$) ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question was quite easier than I thought it would be.

```
<xsl:template match="@*[. = $wildcard]">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name(.)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$wildcard_value"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

I hope it helps someone.

P.S: Here is my full XSL-Transformation to replace wildcards in attributes values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:param name="wildcard" required="yes" />
    <xsl:param name="wildcard_value" required="yes" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*[. = $wildcard]">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name(.)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$wildcard_value" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Note that `match="*/@*[. = $wildacard]"` can be shortened to `match="@*[. = $wildacard]"`. And if you really use XSLT version 3.0 then instead of the first template you have you can simply declare `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`. I also notice that your declared param name is `name="wildcard"`, yet your code references `$wildacard`.

Comment: <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/> only works with the enterprise version of saxon. So i decided to tag the stylesheet as version 2.0